# Composing business logic in an event-sourced system?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

In my understanding, executing a command in an event-sourced system works as follows (simplified):

1. Validate the command DTO itself. Reject if necessary.
2. Load/hydrate the affected aggregate by applying events in order (projection).
3. Validate whether or not the command can be applied from a business perspective by cross-checking the command with the state of the aggregate. Reject if necessary.
4. **Perform business logic on the aggregate. The aggregate itself remains unchanged, so the methods called on/with it just output events which log what happened.**
5. Persist the generated events atomically in the right order.
6. Return to client.

I am interested in the part that performs the business logic. In a non-event-sourced system this is quite simple: Call methods that change the state of the aggregate in a way that maintains its invariants. We can **easily chain and compose method calls**, and easily interchange read and write operations. E.g. after having called a method that changed the state, we can call another one that acts on the new state already. We can do this all locally in one logical transaction.

In an event-sourced system I see no easy way to compose these calls. The first one might emit some events, but the second one does not yet see the effects of these events. This basically means that in the context of one command handler, **I can only read once, and then write once.** I cannot do a back-and-forth like I'm used to in standard OOP.

I can see some alternatives, each with their own drawbacks:

- Create a deep clone of the aggregate before doing any changes, then do usual mutation on it, and finally generate "diff events" by comparing the modified instance with its clone. *Drawback*: The generated events are very low level and very close to the current database schema, which complicates schema evolution.
- In addition to emitting events also modify the state of the aggregate as usual. *Drawback*: Now I have duplicated the projection logic. Who guarantees that applying the generated events later on has the same effect as the method implementation that generated them?
- Apply the generated events on-the-fly (in-memory) using the projection logic, before calling another method, all while still being in the same handler and transaction. *Drawback*: This bloats the business code with infrastructure concerns.

  - **UPDATE**: As noted in the answers, using a custom function composition implementation, it is possible to hide/abstract the ad-hoc projection from user code. This way, each command would take an aggregate and emit a bunch of events, and the composition logic would apply those events to the aggregate using the projection logic, before calling the next command in the chain. See *free monads* for some theoretical background.

So how is business logic composition usually done in an event-sourced system?

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that applying the projection logic in the command handler is bloating the business code with infrastructure concerns.  For an event-sourced aggregate, the core projection logic (a function, in Scala notation, of type `(A, Event) => A`, viz. which takes an aggregate and an event and returns a new aggregate) is the essential part of the aggregate and not an infrastructure concern.

So if such an aggregate has a method (partial Java notation) `A applyEvent(Event e)`, and the command handler is accumulating a sequence of events, folding over the sequence to get a new state (which is duplicating the operation of the projection) doesn't strike me as bloating at all (admittedly, event sourcing is in some sense sneaking functional programming into enterprise development (there's a lot of mechanical sympathy with the free monad), so doing this in a language without some "lambda calculus nature" may be painful).

Setting that aside, you note that diff events are very low level.  Event sourcing tends to favor high level events: emitting "a lot" of events for a command is perhaps a sign that the events want to be higher level descriptions of what (and why) the change happened.  It's OK to have events that get handled in nearly identical ways (e.g. for a message board, a `UserDeletedPost` event and a `ModeratorDeletedPost` event will likely both be interpreted the same way by the `Post` aggregate, but there's a pretty substantial semantic difference between the events) and to have some repeated checks in command handlers.  A tendency in event-sourced systems to have simple aggregates also supports this approach.

In some cases, a particularly coarse-grained command can be decomposed into multiple commands (effectively a saga).  If an aggregate is going to support such coarse-grained commands, it may need to be modified to support an illusion of atomicity for the coarse-grained command.  Event-sourcing implementations which map to the actor model can sometimes simplify this.

Comment: +1 for the *monad* mention. But what is your overall suggestion here? You favor the last alternative, where the projection gets called in-between? How would that look like in clean code? Using a monad, I could see the generated events as the monads side effect/context, and composition would basically just concatenate calls without executing them (similar to the continuation monad). Then there would be a `run` method that simply runs all the code while doing on-the-fly projection in-between? The actual base type `T`of the monad would always be the aggregate itself.

Comment: The other suggestion I'm reading out of your answer is to basically stick to the "read once, then write once" mantra, and whenever you have to do more than one such round, simply model it using a cascade of different commands which are orchestrated by a saga?

Comment: The monadic interpretation is elaborated on (in Scala) in Debashish Ghosh's _Functional and Reactive Domain Modeling_.  Commands become free monads over events (thus commands are composable via monadic bind) and the event interpreter is basically a state monad.

Comment: The saga approach to composing specific commands is basically de-monadifying the monadic view and might look better in a language where introducing monads would obscure things.

Comment: I should also say that I am largely opposed to the "clean code" movement; like the gang of four design pattern movement, I think it over-extrapolates from problems arising at least as much from programming language/library deficiencies as from the essentials of solving those problems.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Regarding the free monad: What would be the argument to the `bind` function? A function that takes `X` and produces an `M(Y)`, where `M` is our monad type, but what are `X` and `Y`? Where are the events and where is the command?

Comment: With "clean code", I only meant bloat-free code. I was not refering to Uncle Bobs book and the movement in general. ;)

Comment: Never mind, I just got the whole "free monad with state monad-like interpreter"-thing after reading up the concepts again and drawing some diagrams. In the end this is just a very pretentious way (looking at you, Debashish) of stating a pretty simple idea: Let commands be functions that take aggregates as input and produce a bunch of events as output, and compose them by applying the event projection mechanism in the background, thus hiding it from the programmer. I have to admit, this a a pretty elegant solution that is easily doable in, say, C#.

Comment: A clearer explication of the free monad is not to be found on SO.

Comment: Monads are always about what composition means for a certain type. As opposed to monads, free monads don't immediately join two monadic structures but defer it until the creator performs the joining explicitly by applying an interpreter. Since joining is what distinguishes a monad from functor/applicative, this is a pretty big deal. You probably know that but it might still be valuable to others.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on that. I understand how it works, but I don't really see the need for using these abstract concepts from category theory to explain or even motivate an elegant solution/design for the problem at hand. One can easily explain and use the idea in much more concrete terms.

Answer (score 1):

In our [reSolve](https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/) framework we end up with one command - one event scheme. Yes, it is a limitation, but it seems the only way to ensure consistency in the concurrent distributed environment. Multi-event logic in this case is performed by sagas.

We may allow to write several events, but, as you correctly mentioned, you cannot evaluate the state between these events, and you cannot/should not write them one-by-one, because some other command can change the aggregate state in between.